# How to save an array of check boxes?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have an array of check boxes and I need to save it when the metro apps shuts down and display it again when the app opens again what is the best way to do it? I tried using roaming settings but you cant save check boxes that way...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to save the `Checkboxes`? What you can do is just save an array of required data to be displayed again in checkboxes.

So what you want to do is create an object that backs up the checkboxes datacontext.

Say you only want the Width, Height, and IsChecked property of the checkbox. So when you need to load them back, you'll just let the UI do it's own thing and then back it up again with the persisted properties of the checkbox

Comment: Create a class that will contain the properties you want to store. Then on each of your Checkbox, set the `DataContext` to that class. After that, you can persist each of those objects i.e., serializing it.

Comment: Can you show me how to do the serializing maybe some sample code?